# How can I refactor this model in Django?

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models, refactoring

I want to refactor this model(code) from Django so that I can take as many inputs as required without writing a lot of code or efficiently. Or Can I use for loop in models?

**models.py**

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prescribed_doctor = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=150)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sales_medicine_1 = models.ForeignKey(Medicines,related_name='sales_medicine',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Med_quantity_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=False,default=1)
    Free_quantity_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    margin_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    discount_1 = models.FloatField(choices=dis,default=0,null=True)
    discount_1_amt = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True)
    rate_1 = models.FloatField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    batch_no_1 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=50)
    mfg_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    expiry_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    sales_medicine_2 = models.ForeignKey(Medicines,blank=True,null=True,related_name='sales_medicine_1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Med_quantity_2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    Free_quantity_2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    margin_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    discount_2 = models.FloatField(choices=dis,default=0,null=True)
    discount_2_amt = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True)
    rate_2 = models.FloatField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    batch_no_2 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=50)
    mfg_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    expiry_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    sales_medicine_3 = models.ForeignKey(Medicines,blank=True,null=True,related_name='sales_medicine_2',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Med_quantity_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    Free_quantity_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    margin_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    discount_3 = models.FloatField(choices=dis,default=0,null=True)
    discount_3_amt = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True)
    rate_3 = models.FloatField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    batch_no_3 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=50)
    mfg_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    expiry_3 = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=payment_status)
    Paid_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    auto_generated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Create a second model with the repeating items and a foreign key to the Sales model.

Comment: Yes, I can do that but can't i use for loop in a model?

Comment: No, a class is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution - just use `ManytoManyField()`.

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prescribed_doctor = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sales_medicine = models.ManytoManyField(Medicines)
```

Here is the documentation to many to many relationships in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/